# Procura uma variável no JSP

Tags: netbeans, jsp

Trabalho com várias páginas JSP que se comunicam, e atualmente preciso encontrar uma variável que está presente em várias páginas, preciso encontrar onde ela está sendo declarada.

Comment: Está usando alguma IDE/editor de código ?

Comment: usando netbeans

Answer (score 1):

Existe a Opção "Buscar em Projetos" que você encontra a partir do menu "Editar". Nela tem vários parâmetros que você insere para efetuar a busca, tais como:

- Palavra a ser pesquisada nos projetos
- Extensão de arquivo;
- Projeto a ser pesquisado;

Estou usando a versão 8 e funcionou.

> Fonte:
>   http://pt.wingwit.com/P/java-programming/89248.html#.U205lyjpx0c

Comment: sim, mas a ferramenta so busca na pagina na qual procuro, e não é nenhuma delas